# flalign* formulas leftbound

Tags: math-mode, align, empheq

I'm using an align-like environment (employing the `empheq` package) to display a formal system where I want to display two parts with a surrounding box. My problem is: I want the equations on the right-hand side to move in a aligned way to the left but I can't figure out how to do it. Here is my code for this part.

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
  &\text{Part 1}\\
  &\text{(A1)} &&x=x\\
  &\text{Part 2}\\
  &\text{(K)} &&y=y
\end{empheq}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
  & \text{Part 1} & \\
  & x=x & \text{(A1)} \\
  & \text{Part 2} & \\
  & y=y & \text{(K)}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Or even better (in my opinion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\eqsection[1]{\text{\underline{#1}}}
\newcommand*\intag{\text}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
  \eqsection{Part 1} && \\
  & x=x & \intag{(A1)} \\
  \eqsection{Part 2} && \\
  & y=y & \intag{(K)}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Finally, an alternative approach that may fit your goal way better (avoiding the `empheq` package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
  \section*{Part 1}
  \begin{equation*}
    x=x \tag{A1}
  \end{equation*}
  \section*{Part 2}
  \begin{equation*}
    y=y \tag{K}
  \end{equation*}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i underline part 1 and part 2 ?

Comment: @zzuussee, sure! `\text{\underline{Part 1}}`. And there is even a better option. I'll update the answer...

Comment: I actually meant something like a hline through the complete box

Comment: @zzuussee, this is a topic on its own. I guess it has been asked similarly alredy. If not, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the math part centered; for this you need a further alignment point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
& \text{Part 1}\\
& \text{(A1)} & x&=a & \\
& \text{Part 2} \\
& \text{(K)}  & y&=c+d &
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible refinement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{flalign*}
& \textit{Part 1}\\
& \text{(A1)} & x&=a & \\[1ex]
& \textit{Part 2} \\
& \text{(K)}  & y&=c+d &
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]